# how do I sign Tronix transaction locally in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, cryptography, digital-signature

I've been using: https://github.com/cobowallet/tron-wallet

it has method `.generateTransaction(to, amount, token, latestBlock)`
but, what it return is not exactly an Object, I can just pass to `/wallet/broadcasttransaction` (ref: https://github.com/tronprotocol/Documentation/blob/master/TRX/Tron-http.md)

I've been checking the example in:
https://github.com/tronprotocol/wallet-cli/blob/master/src/main/java/org/tron/demo/TransactionSignDemo.java

but I can't seem to find, how to do:
`transaction.getRawData().toByteArray()`

since I can't seem to resolve  `import org.tron.protos.Protocol.Transaction;` 
any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cobowallet is easiest to sign and generate a tronix transaction. Here is an example:

```
    const parentNode = TronWallet.fromMnemonic('all all all all all all all all all all all all')
    const node = parentNode.derivePath("m/49'/195'/0'/0/0")
    const latestBlock = {
      hash: '000000000046b520515cd81609c969e5659568bf360859f7e5493ceedd6ec41d',
      number: 4633888,
      timestamp: 1543869858000
    }

    const tx = node.generateTransaction('TR2a3x6tX5trbhaTBU71Fpi1SWYj8gKEGy', 5000000, 'TRX', latestBlock)
    console.log(tx.hex)
    console.log(tx.txid)
```

But make sure that latest block is up to date. You can use this URL ([getnowblock](https://api.trongrid.io/wallet/getnowblock)) to fetch the latest block from the blockchain.